# How to Display Points and Linestrings Together in Vega

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to display both points and linestrings in the same visualization, but can't get it to work. Here is the JSON configuration I'm using:

https://vega.github.io/editor/?#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-7BGEEQZgw+Q4Occ69gUbDgQA6ooyimnq0FEpiD5cqaub5venKKls5EqreaQQEkCBMGwVxPmwL4gG+rj3oWURfj+bB-j2gFwMBpoAB4gToA42NAYRwAAFAA5GW9ZyROb4MAglAgg64KRG46ijAAlIhSRif2YSSW25zyYpwrKeOqnqZpYLVBAbjzAZiGgShEHYWk+RwHKmKeWhGEEaAPn6IFljeVBvjzOo8WYkcoSEmFMU2Ew+pkeR2xAA

All the examples I've found typically pull from external URLs, I'll be pulling the objects from a local tabular source. Just starting my journey in Vega and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this for Power BI?

Comment: @DavideBacci No, but a big fan of your work :)

Comment: Found a solution: 
DATA: {
      "name": "points",
      "values": [
        {"lon": -77.05, "lat": 38.9}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "geopoint",
          "projection": "projection",
          "fields": ["lon", "lat"]
        }
      ]
    }
MARKS: {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "points"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "size": {"value": 1000},
          "fill": {"value": "black"}
        },
        "update": {"x": {"field": "x"}, "y": {"field": "y"}}
      }
    }